# Can I disenchant the Archmage's Robes?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have never have been able to disenchant the Archmage's Robes, but I don't have 100 enchanting yet so maybe that's why.

You know the duplication glitch that allows you to put a piece of armor on the mannequins in the house in solitude then take it off the mannequins leave and go back inside your house and it is on the mannequins for you to collect. Well I wanted to know if you could use this trick with the Archmage's Robes and after getting a duplicate from this trick you'll be able to disenchant the duplicate?

Answer (score 7):

Disenchanting is not tied to the enchanting skill. You can't disenchant the archmage's robes, period.

**EDIT**: Of course, with the right mods (available via skyrim.nexusmods.com or the steam workshop), or just the right console commands, you can do pretty much anything.

Comment: Except if you get a mod that lets you disenchant everything. (They exist, but can't search, at work and such)

Comment: Given that you can do pretty much anything with a mod, that's not necessarily a useful modifier to the answer.

Comment: True, but not everyone is aware of what mods can do. I just wanted to show the user one other option that he has.